Movie about a man stranded on an island who seeks revenge
I saw a portion of this movie a while ago and wanted to watch it from the beginning - the story goes roughly like this:
The main character is a sailor of sorts and ends up stranded on an island - he finds treasure on the island and somehow escapes to the mainland with a lot of $$ - he then goes on impersonating all sorts of other characters in order to get back at the people which caused him to end up stranded on the island. Among his impersonation titles, one of them is a monk, another is a wealthy count. There was also some plot involving re-building a ship that sunk, and a (pistol) duel where he was challenged to but could not kill the challenger, thus he loads blanks or something in his gun. 
The Audio was in French, but I think there were English subtitles. It was ~10 years ago when I saw it and the movie is older.

Some of it sounds like the plot of The Count of Monte Cristo, but I'm not sure it all fits. How old was this film, exactly? Was it a drama?

@Walt I think that's it, but now that I am looking it up on google there are a bunch of different versions, and I don't know which one it was exactly (it was ~10 years ago when I saw it, movie is older..)

Yes, there were certainly many adaptations... A somewhat recent (1998) miniseries based on it starred Gerard Depardieu, does that help?

@Walt ah, that's the one - it was a TV series not a movie apparently (feel free to post it as an answer)

No problem. :) Glad you found it.

1998 miniseries The Count of Monte Cristo with Gerard Depardieu.

A TV mini-series adaptation of the classic Alexandre Dumas novel. Edmond Dantes is falsely accused by those jealous of his good fortune, and is sentenced to spend the rest of his life in the notorious island prison, Chateau d'If. While imprisoned, he meets the Abbe Faria, a fellow prisoner whom everyone believes to be mad. The Abbe tells Edmond of a fantastic treasure hidden away on a tiny island, that only he knows the location of. After many years in prison, the old Abbe dies, and Edmond escapes disguised as the dead body. Now free, Edmond must find the treasure the Abbe told him of, so he can use the new-found wealth to exact revenge on those who have wronged him. 


